# Out of space error in iPhone

Tags: iphone, file-io, storage

In iPhone, how do you determine if a file couldn't be written to the documents area because of an out of space error?

Comment: In this particular case with fwrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fwrite` returns the number of items written, so you can check if it's consistent to know if there's any errors:

```
if (fwrite(data, sizeof(Something), 1234, fp) != 1234) {
  // handle error.
}
```

This is the only documented way to check if a `fwrite` failure (including out-of-space error) happens.

Comment: Should probably also do a fflush() and check the status of that.